# How can I trace tiny reconnects/disconnects to my wireless network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

A few days ago I moved to a new appartment where I use a provided wireless network.

However, the connection is very unstable from time to time. I often get connection drops and it is getting pretty annoying as I just can't rely on my network doing its job.

However, I am currently connecting to my network with a wifi stick plugged into my desktop PC. It is not the first time I am using this stick, and I can recall having a lot of problems with it, so I don't want to blame the network for any problems immediately.

Instead, I would like to run some kind of analyzer on my desktop PC and my notebook, which has an integrated option of accessing wifi, in order to analyze if the problem is actually the network or if it is my stick.

I don't really know how to do this, though. I'm having trouble finding software which even records tiny outages, as they are often so short, that it may occur in between a measurement interval.

Is there any advice on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: If the WiFi dongle wobbles, it might be the issue. Try taping it in place. Also, how strong is the signal? Finally, look for interference, such as a noisy electrical device.

Comment: Sounds like you have two problems. You are in a tightly populated area (an apartment) and you are using a shared WiFi internet service - possibly provided by the apartment I presume? This is your new norm sorry to say. Your only solution is to purchase your own internet service and run strictly on the 5Ghz band and even then it’s not guaranteed to never have issues. That is the nature of WiFi. There is no reason to get fancy trying to test this. If both computers are having the same problem then there is nothing further to test. Respectfully, your expectations are too high.

Comment: @Appleoddity Your assumptions are correct. I may have the option to purchase my own service over TV cable, but I'm not sure about that as well.